# Etymology of 'Sobremesa'

Tags: etimología, historia

I was told in another post that the origin of 'sobremesa' may have originated from table-cloth as 'sobremesa' can be directly translated to as over-table. I would like to learn more about the origin or development of 'sobremesa. If someone could share it history or even any corpus/famous song about 'sobremesa' it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *sobremesa* has meant several things. The primitive meaning is the least figurative: it means a cover that is put over a table; later it evolved to include ornaments that were placed on the table while not in use (e.g. *reloj de sobremesa*, "tabletop clock").

Another meaning was "dessert". The current Spanish word for "dessert", and for the time after the main meal where one eats dessert, is *postre*, cognate with Latin *posterus* "following" and with Spanish *postrero* "last". This meaning of *sobremesa* has disappeared (though it persists in modern Portuguese, which is closely related to Spanish).

The prefix *sobre-* primarily means "over, above" (Latin *super*), but it also means "after" and "additionally" by extension; *mesa*, besides "table", refers figuratively to the food that is served on the table, and to the occasion of eating a meal. So *sobremesa*, by associating these two figurative meanings, came to mean "the time after a meal", "the extra time spent at the table after a meal" and "the extra food consumed after the main meal".

These meanings seem to exist already in early modern Spanish. In *Reloj de príncipes* by Fray Antonio de Guevara (1529-1531) we have *sobremesa* as "time after the main meal" presented as a time where people joke around and speak without seriousness:

> *Presupuesto que son tales los que lo dizen y adonde lo dizen, que es sobremesa, dignos son de perdonar, pues hablan no según los libros que avían leýdo, sino según los manjares que avían comido; porque muy poco sabe de burla el que no toma lo que se dize sobremesa de burla.*

(This means, in case you find it difficult, that you must forgive and forget mockery after a meal, i.e. during *sobremesa*, because people don't talk then "by the books they've read, but by the victuals they've eaten".)

In other texts *sobremesa* is used as adverb, meaning "after a meal":

> *E aquellos caualleros que allí çenauan, algunos se fueron luego, e otros quedaron hablando sobremesa...* (Gonzalo Fernández de Oviedo, *Batallas y quinquagenas*, 1535-c.1552)
>
> *Y, madre, por tu vida, que sobremesa, ya que hemos comido, cuentes al señor Grajales y a mi prima el cuento de lo que te acaeció...* (Feliciano de Silva, *Segunda Celestina*, 1534)

(In these last two texts the implication is that people stay and talk *sobremesa*, i.e. after eating their meal.)

In a few texts it's possible to guess that *sobremesa* implies extra food, but the meaning of "dessert" seems to have died out soon, leaving us only with the meaning of "easy time at the table after eating".

You can [look for *sobremesa* in the CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=4&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=50&FID=280219%5C021%5CC053O28022019213427516.1016.1012&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20sobremesa%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D0-1900%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0), a big digitized corpus of Spanish-language texts.